# add external modules and libraries into my own module in python

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I always have to import certain libraries and modules on day to day basis when i am working with data analysis using jupyter notebook. Recently, I started developing my own module where I can define the most common functions that I use daily so that I only call this module in jupyter and then I have access to all the functions.

I was wondering if I could also declare libraries such as pandas, numpy etc. in a function in my module and then load this function as a pre-step in jupyter so that the data processing environment is setup and i don't have to declare the required libraries repeatedly when working in different notebooks.

I tried using the following options but jupyter does not seem to recognize the "pd" variable (as an example) from my module:

```
import pandas as pd
global pd = import pandas
global import pandas as __pd__
```

Can anyone suggest how to tackle this issue?

NOTE: pandas is just an example, I will to add more libraries and settings such as utf-8 encoding in my module.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my question by following the instructions in this link: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-automatically-import-your-favorite-libraries-into-ipython-or-a-jupyter-notebook-9c69d89aa343

Steps to follow:

1. Navigate to **~/.ipython/profile_default**
2. Create a folder called **startup** if it’s not already there
3. Add a new Python file called **start.py**
4. Put your favorite imports in this file
5. Launch Jupyter Notebook & your favorite libs will be auto loaded.